# How to check for column not present in data returned by a MySQL query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "Pops" and "Customers".  I check to see if a customer has a Pop by querying an inner join of the Pops table and the Customers table.  If that returns no rows, I check to see if the customer exists (another SQL query).  I know it seems backwards, but it reduces the number of steps for our customers (they can check for a Pop and login simultaneously) and also reduces the number of queries for the most common transactions.  I've Googled and also searched SO, but all the answers relate to finding rows, not columns.

The Customers table does not have a PopID column so I am using an if statement:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if (is_null($row["PopID"]) || $row["PopID"]=="") {
    $y = "None";    
} else {
    $y = $row["PopID"];
}
```

However, I get an "Undefined index: " error on the line corresponding to the if statement.  Why won't the is_null check for a missing column?  Is there a different, more correct way to check for this?  Note that PopID can be an empty column in the first query so I need to check for that also.

P.S. Have tried isset($row["PopID"]) as well and I get the same error.

Comment: As I remembered `fetch_assoc()` returns Array. Loop records and then check $row['PopId']

Comment: I haven't shown all the code, but yes, I am checking $count = $result->num_rows; before getting to this point and only do this for count =1 but in fact there is no condition when there is more than one row.

Comment: Perhaps an outer join would suit here?

Comment: Let me clarify, other than this, the code is all working!  I can get the values of  $row["FullName"],  $row["Phone"] etc. from the same $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  So the problem is exactly in that line containing the If, not in the join and not in the array parsing etc.

Comment: You can use `array_key_exists` to see if the column exists, or `isset` to check if it exists and is `<> null`. But it would be a bad habbit in this case. You should have a known data structure at this point. Without knowing the rest of your code I can only guess, but you can probably use a `left join` instead of an `inner join` to check for your pops, then you can do both things simultaneously and end up with the same data structure here. Or set a variable when you use your second query (without the pop-join)  and check this variable first to see if there should be a `popid`-column or not.

Comment: Thanx @Solarflare Adding the array_key_exists did not work, I get the same error.  The left join did work because the PopID field appears, and I am going ahead that for now because I have to finish the  project.  However, I am not too sanguine about breaking something else, because I am using a SQL parser (to prevent SQL injection) that works across the whole application.  So, a better solution (I was optimistic about array_key_exists) please!

Comment: Well, `array_key_exists` (and `isset`) should work. Maybe post the code you tried, including the error message and a dump of your `$row`-variable (after `fetch_assoc`). Also, as mentioned, the `left join` method is actually the most consistent way to do it.